# Combining 2 tables- Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

When i join 2 tables i am getting an error

```
select * from picture where id=(SELECT id FROM user where age= 40 )
```

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

What is the best way to join these 2 large data tables? I want to have all the results

Comment: you are not joining 2 tables, you are selecting from one table and qualifying the result set based on the result from another table. In this case, there were 2 ids in USER table where age is 40. Please tell what you exactly want?

Comment: @beck03076: i.e. the OP is semi-joining the tables...

Comment: @LukasEder: Yes Lukas, semi-joining is not a join, is it?. Anyway thanks for the correction. I dont understand his design. He is comparing picture_id with user_id, did you notice?

Comment: @beck03076: I'm not sure what the OP understands when he says `join`. Maybe he did mean a semi-join... I noticed the weird join predicate. I mentioned it in my answer, too.

Comment: @LukasEder: I just saw your answer, cool! let me write an answer too, after all thats what we do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `=` by `IN`

```
select * from picture where id in (select id from user where age = 40)
```

Note, this is only "semi-joining" the two tables, i.e. you will only get pictures as results, not a picture-user relation. If you're actually trying to do the latter, then you'll have to `inner join` the two tables:

```
select * from picture p
join user u on p.id = u.id -- are you sure about this join condition?
where u.age = 40
```

Answer (score 3):

In the where clause, when you assign a value to `id`, SQL expects a single value. The problem is that the second query `SELECT id FROM user where age= 40` returns more than one row.

What you can do is

```
select * 
from picture 
where id in
    (select id from user where age = 40)
```

**or**

```
select *
from picture p, user u
where p.id = u.id
and u.age = 40
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using 'IN' instead of '='

```
select * from picture where id IN (SELECT id FROM user where age= 40 )
```

Comment: A join is the proper way to do it!

Comment: True, however we don't have all the info to create the join query IMO. The above join examples seem to compare picture id with person id, as Lukas says :)

Comment: So, that's what you need to make the join.

Answer (score 2):

**From what Im guessing out of what Im seeing,**

You have a "picture" table and a "user" table.

1. Table names should be plurals. Make it "pictures" and "users".
2. Define your relationships first. In your case, one user has_many pictures and one picture belongs_to one user.(One picture [on a peaceful world] wont belong to many users).
3. In your pictures table, have an "user_id" column and populate that column with the appropriate user_ids.
4. Now,

**You want all the pictures of users whose ages are exactly 40.**

You can do a,

```
SELECT *   
FROM pictures 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id 
                  FROM users 
                  WHERE user_age = 40)
```

Was that your requirement?. Do I make any sense?